# Windows.UpdateServices.Administration.dll for .Net framework 2?

Tags: c#, service

I installed Remote Server Administration Tools to get Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) API DLL. Problem is that only .net4 DLL is installed. Where/how can I get WSUS API DLL for .net2?

Answer (score 0):

I created new Windows 7 virtual machine, installed only net 2.0/3.5 via "Turn windows features on/off" and downloaded https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5216

Now it's right version. Not sure if the reason was different os version, different package from microsoft or the lack of net4, though.